# jquery validation use variable in rules

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I have a jsp file from which i am passing json objects to a JS file. These json objects need to be consumed for validation purpose and should use jquery validation framework. Below is the code that i have written. All the validation should occur onfoucusout event.

```
setupFormValidation: function()
    {
        $("#tool-form").validate({
onfocusout: function (element) {
    $(element).valid();
    ruleVar=$('#fieldToBeValidated').val()+":"+$('#rule').val();
        //ruleVar=ruleVar.replace(/["]/g, "")
        //alert(ruleVar);
},
            rules:{ 
                 firstName:{required:true,checkRegex:true} //checkRegex is my custom method
     });
     }
```

The variable ruleVar has exactly the same content as mentioned inside rules i.e. firstName...

If i am trying to use ruleVar inside rules then firebug tells me that ":" is missing, and if am writing a custom method that returns the ruleVar then also errors can be seen in firebug.

rules:methodName() // this method returns the output of rulevar,

seems like custom variables cannot be used in jquery validation. Pls suggest an alternative.

Comment: This is not the [tag:jquery-validation-engine] plugin.  Please be more careful when tagging.  Thanks. Edited tags.

Comment: Please construct a more complete example.  Where is the HTML markup for the form?  Where is the `checkRegex` method?

Comment: I found the solution to the problem. This can be achieved using 
this.settings.rules.firstName =ruleConst;  // where ruleConst is the json pattern string and firstName is the name of the field to be validated.

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a closing ')'

```
setupFormValidation: function()
{
        $("#tool-form").validate({
            onfocusout: function (element) {
                $(element).valid();
                ruleVar=$('#fieldToBeValidated').val()+":"+$('#rule').val();
                //ruleVar=ruleVar.replace(/["]/g, "")
                //alert(ruleVar);
            },
            rules:{ 
                 firstName:{"required":true,"checkRegex":"true"}
            }
        });
}
```

Comment: sorry, that was typo, i have corrected the code above. The error is not coming because of that.